# Spring data neo4j 3 with embedded neo 2

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

im working on my scaffold and i can't seem to get Neo embedded to initialize.  I am using Neo 2, so I am running spring data 3.0.0.m1.  I can't get it to light up.  Here is my context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.onuspride.wisdom" />

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <import resource="spring-data-Neo4j.xml" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <bean id="jotm" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.JotmFactoryBean"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <constructor-arg value="target/test-db"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="tx_manager_impl" value="spring-jta"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

But i get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [java.lang.Iterable]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
```

I can't find anything anywhere saying there are more constructor parameters.

here's my dependencies

```
akka = '2.2.3'
        akkaSeries = '_2.10'
        apacheLog4jVersion = '2.0-beta9'
        aspectjVersion = '1.7.2'
        cglibVersion = '2.2.2'
        commonsCodecVersion = '1.5'
        commonsDigesterVersion = '2.1'
        commonsFileuploadVersion = '1.3'
        commonsLang3Version = '3.1'
        elApiVersion = '1.0'
        fasterxmlJacksonVersion = '2.3.0'
        flexJsonVersion = '2.1'
        ginVersion = '2.0.0'
        googleAPIClient = '1.17.0-rc'
        googleAPIDrive = 'v2-rev110-1.17.0-rc'
        googleAPIOauth2 = 'v2-rev59-1.17.0-rc'
        googleJackson = '1.15.0-rc'
        guavaVersion = '14.0.1'
        guiceVersion = '3.0'
        gwtpVersion = '1.0.3'
        gwtqueryVersion = '1.3.2'
        gwtsecurityVersion = '1.2.3'
        gwtVersion = '2.5.1'
        hamcrestDateVersion = '0.9.5'
        hibernateValidator = '5.0.2.Final'
        ioSpray = '1.2.0'
        javaxServletVersion = '3.0.1'
        jedisVersion = '2.1.0'
        jettyVersion = '9.1.0.v20131115'
        jodaTimeVersion = '1.6'
        json4sVersion = '3.2.6'
        jspApiVersion = '2.1'
        jstlApiVersion = '1.2'
        jukitoVersion = '1.1'
        junitVersion = '4.11'
        lmaxDistruptorVersion = '3.2.0'
        neo4jVersion = '2.0.0'
        persistenceApiVersion = '1.0'
        scalaLangVersion = '2.10.2'
        slf4jVersion = '1.7.5'
        socialSigninTwitterVersion = '1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        //springDataNeo4jVersion = '2.3.3.RELEASE'
        springDataNeo4jVersion = '3.0.0.M1'
        springDataRedis = '1.1.0.RELEASE'
        springJsResourcesVerison = '2.3.2.RELEASE'
        springJsVersion = '2.3.2.RELEASE'
        springScalaVersion = '1.0.0.RC1'
        springSecurityVersion = '3.2.0.RELEASE'
        springSocialGoogleVersion = '1.0.0.M3'
        springSocialVersion = '1.1.0.M4'
        springVersion = '3.2.6.RELEASE'
        tilesJspVersion = '2.2.2'

compile "com.lmax:disruptor:$lmaxDistruptorVersion"
        compile "com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor$akkaSeries:$akka"
        compile "com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j$akkaSeries:$akka"
        compile "io.spray:spray-can:$ioSpray"
        compile "io.spray:spray-routing:$ioSpray"
        compile "joda-time:joda-time:$jodaTimeVersion"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:$apacheLog4jVersion"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:$apacheLog4jVersion"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:$apacheLog4jVersion"
        compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:$hibernateValidator"
        compile "org.json4s:json4s-native_2.10:$json4sVersion"
        compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:$scalaLangVersion"
        compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-aspects:$springDataNeo4jVersion"
        compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-tx:$springDataNeo4jVersion"
        compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:$springDataNeo4jVersion"
        compile "org.springframework.scala:spring-scala_2.10:$springScalaVersion"
        compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:$springVersion"
        compile "org.springframework:spring-aspects:$springVersion"
        compile "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion"
        compile "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion"
        compile "org.springframework:spring-tx:$springVersion"
        compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j', version: "$neo4jVersion"
        compile group: 'org.neo4j.app', name: 'neo4j-server', version: "$neo4jVersion", classifier: 'static-web'
        testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"
        testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data Neo4j 3.0.M1 only works with Neo4j 2.0.0-M06

The next milestone is almost ready, which then will work with Neo4j 2.0.0

Comment: oh your kidding me.  I've been working on this for a day and a half.  ugh.  It would be awesome if Spring would publish a table of what everything is built against in an easy to find area, maybe an appendix in the document or something.  it would make life so much easier.  Thank you, it worked great.

Comment: Now im getting errors that it can't find the neo4j-cypher-dsl library, but I can't find that library in the 2.0 repository, the oldest i can find is 1.8.  any ideas on that?

Comment: You should be able to find it in the maven repo m2.neo4j.org

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Changing spring-data.xml to the following helped resolve the issue...

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor"/>
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase"
      destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
</bean>
<bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
<constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
</bean>    
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/db/data"/>
<neo4j:repositories base-package="org.example.repository"/>
```